# Updating Already Checked Checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

let's say I have a list of checkboxes that the user selects.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Water" />Water<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Cable" />Cable<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Electricity" />Electricity<br />
etc...
```

The user selected Water and it is added to the database.  Now the user wants to update the list:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Water" checked="checked"/>Water<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Cable" />Cable<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Electricity" />Electricity<br />
etc...
```

How can I check that the utility has already been checked in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done in the past, to save having hundreds of lines of bloat is this...

First compile all the html in a variable, without any "checked" instances.

```
$boxes = '';
$boxes .= '<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Water" />Water<br />';
$boxes .= '<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Cable" />Cable<br />';
$boxes .= '<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Electricity" />Electricity<br />';
```

Now I loop over your array of fields to check. I've provided a sample array here too.

```
$already_checked = array('Water', 'Electricity');

foreach( $already_checked as $ac ) {
    $find = 'value="' . $ac . '"';
    $replace = $find . ' checked="checked"';
    $boxes = str_replace($find, $replace, $boxes);
}

echo $boxes;
```

Comment: This will work, but it's unintuitive, and it's not especially efficient. Linearly searching through a string is hardly a better or more performant solution that a catch-all method or a well-structured `if` statement.

Comment: Stewart, you're missing the point. It's far easier to maintain large lists of checkboxes with the above method (i.e. as plain html), than editing separate if statements for each input. I agree that technically it's a more brute force method, but it makes the code cleaner.

Comment: But then you have to manually list the checked array in every instance. A better solution is to generate it dynamically (as well as the checkboxes themselves) so that any future changes or additions will not require rewriting the arrays or the form element values manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" value="Water" 
     <?= in_array('Water', $utilities) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>" 
/>
```

(The `$utilities` variable above is a stand-in for something like `$_REQUEST['utilities']`, depending on how your code is structured.)

Comment: Is there any way of doing it differently than having an if statement in every single checkbox form? I have about 50 of them, and that seems inefficient.

Comment: For efficiency, you can pull all the checkbox values into an array of booleans (assuming there aren't thousands of them). Then you can do something like this: `<?= $values['Water'] ? 'checked="checked" : '' ?>`

Comment: But yes, you will effectively need an `if` or ternary operator for each `input`. That doesn't mean it will be inefficient, though, because those are very simple operators. The performance issue will simply be how you pull the data from your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="utility[]" id="utility[]" value="Water"
   <?php
   if(isAlreadyChecked("Water"))
     echo "checked=\"checked\""
   ?>
/>Water<br />

<?php
   function isAlreadyChecked(value)
   {
     //Check if it is already checked and return a boolean
   }
?>
```

Comment: As I said below, is there a more efficient way of doing it that you can think of?  I am trying to think right now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every variant of the `in_array` conditional out there and could NEVER get this to work (checking off the checkboxes whose values had been previously selected and thus inserted into the database).  I tried complex queries with table joins and no luck with that either.  I finally gave up and generated a `display:hidden` `div` that opened the array (which for some odd reason I had to IMPLODE rather than explode) and listed its items as comma-separated text.  Then I tossed in a little jQuery `indexOf()` magic to determine if the value of each checkbox was part of said array or not.  Took me 10 minutes flat to do this with jQuery, very simple.

Here's some sample code that is live and working fine:

```
<div class="categories">
  <span class="keywords"><?php $categories = array(); $categories = implode(', ', $keywords); echo $categories ?></span>
  <em>Please verify category selections with each update.</em><br/>
  <?php
    include 'db.php'; 
      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categoriesTable ORDER BY Category_Name ASC");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
        $key = urldecode($row['Category_Name']);
        $id = urlencode($row['catID']);
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='Category_Key[]' value='$id' id='cat_$id' $chk> $key<br/>";
        }
  ?>
</div>
```

CSS sets that div to invisible:

```
.keywords { display:none; visibility:hidden; }
```

and the jQuery portion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.categories input').each(function(index,data) {
        var str=$('.keywords').text();
        var catid = $(this).val();
        var chk = str.indexOf(catid);
        if (chk >= 0) {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps someone else who is stuck wondering why the `in_array` conditional is failing them.  Since this falls in a twilight zone between data and UI regarding data persistence, I think it's a legit route to take.  You have one "echo" statement to generate multiple checkboxes (there are around 40 categories in my situation here) and then a simple jQuery `.each()` to locate what was selected before and render its corresponding boxes as checked.