# Need html checkbox to be checked by mysql result

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

My need is to check a checkbox by mysql select result...

Here is my mysql table

```
username | hobbies              
----------------------------
abc      | reading painting
```

When I select username 'abc' and submit,it goes to edit page..

In that page I need to edit hobbies..

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="reading">Reading
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="painting">painting
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="gaming">gaming
</body>
<html>
```

When I select 'abc' with hobbies reading and painting,only the first & second checkboxes must be checked...How can i do that with php,mysql??? pls help.....

Comment: Are you sure you want to save the hobbies like that? What if a hobby is introduced with a space in it like "bike riding" or something like that. I would choose for a relational approach by saving them in a separate table, or at least seperation the values with a `,` or `;` character

Comment: normalise the data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the database record to seperate array entries

```
<?php
    $hobbies = explode(" ", $mysql_result['hobbies']);
?>
```

Then check for each value if the array contains the value and set the checkbox to checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="reading" <?php if(in_array("reading", $hobbies)) echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>Reading
```

Comment: when i apply ur code i'm getting a warning....Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: first I coded $paym=explode("  ",$hby); the variable $hby is mysql result...after that I have used foreach($paym as $k)
  {
  echo $k; } The $k stores all elements in field, ie reading and painting...I have used if(in_array("reading",$k)) echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?> in checkbox...but gettin warning.....pls help...

Comment: Did you do the first step aswell? It turns the mysql result containg the hobbies field into an array by splitting it with the space character

Comment: You need to check if the value is in the array so in your case: `if(in_array("reading",$paym))`

Comment: yes!!!!!! it works......I have used if(in_array("reading",$paym))..then it got checked...thank you a lot........

Comment: can I make a checkbox with javascript??by using mysql result?? Can I pass php values to a javascript variable??

Comment: Sure you can do it in javascript. Parse the results to json, loop the json results with jquery and select the appropriate checkbox based on the value.

Comment: I tried three different syntax variants of that in_array conditional and none of them worked to check the appropriate boxes with values corresponding to my array.  In the end I gave up and used jQuery to do it instead.  Here's my solution if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26433841/1896348

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the HTML tags as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="reading" checked="checked" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="reading" <?php echo status;?>>Reading
```

And then have your php determine the status of the check box based on your SQL query and store it in the variable

```
status
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your schema. Each field is supposed to be atomic - having one value.

Create a hobby table, alter the users table, add a table to enable a many to many relationship between users and hobbies. Create a view showing a user with their hobbies.

This means you'll be able to execute queries like.

```
select * from `hobby` ; -- means your hobby check box can now be created dynamically
select * from `username_hobby` where username_id = 1 ; -- means you already have the username hobbies as separate elements.
```

More detail on data normalisation => https://www.google.com.au/search?q=atomic+data+normalization

sqlfiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdef/1/0

suggested schema below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hobby`;

CREATE TABLE `hobby` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hobby` varchar(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `hobby` (`id`, `hobby`)
VALUES
    (1,'reading'),
    (2,'painting'),
    (3,'gaming');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `username`;

CREATE TABLE `username` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(31) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `username` (`id`, `username`)
VALUES
    (1,'abc');


DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `username_hobbies_view`;

CREATE TABLE `username_hobbies_view` (
   `username` VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT '',
   `hobby` VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
   `username_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `hobby_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `username_hobby`;

CREATE TABLE `username_hobby` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hobby_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username_relationship` (`username_id`),
  KEY `hobby_relationship` (`hobby_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `hobby_relationship` FOREIGN KEY (`hobby_id`) REFERENCES `hobby` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `username_relationship` FOREIGN KEY (`username_id`) REFERENCES `username` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `username_hobby` (`id`, `username_id`, `hobby_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,1,2);

DROP TABLE `username_hobbies_view`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `username_hobbies_view`
AS SELECT
   `username`.`username` AS `username`,
   `hobby`.`hobby` AS `hobby`,
   `username_hobby`.`username_id` AS `username_id`,
   `username_hobby`.`hobby_id` AS `hobby_id`
FROM ((`username` join `username_hobby` on((`username`.`id` = `username_hobby`.`username_id`))) join `hobby` on((`hobby`.`id` = `username_hobby`.`hobby_id`)));
```

Comment: thanx 4 ur reply bro....here my checkboxes are not to be created dynamically...checkboxes already created with html and i need to check these boxes with mysql result..

Comment: @vyshakh hard coding leads to hard maintenance. What happens when another hobby is added? What happens if someone asks for a French version? WHat happens if you have another application other than a web browser manipulating the data?

Comment: u r absolutely right...If another hobby is added in field,its much difficult to edit the html code..but i think thre is no more hobbies to be added in this case...

Comment: You may as well learn about data normalisation now @vyshakh. Your current approach will cause you problems in the future.