# Checkbox not checked based on database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to display a checked checkbox if the store has been assigned a value in the database, i have the following but am not sure why it is not working, it is currently not checking any checkboxes even though they have values assigned.

```
$stores = array();
    $stmt = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT `id`, `store`, `store_name`, `branch_name` FROM `mystores` WHERE `site` = :site ORDER BY `store_name` ASC, `branch_name` ASC');
    $stmt->param(':site', $this->permissions['site'][0]);
    try {
        $result = $stmt->execute()->as_array();
        if (count($result) >= 1) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $checked = in_array($row['store'], $assigns) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                $stores[] = '<label><input type="checkbox" name="stores['.$row['store'].']" value="'.$row['store'].'"'.$checked.' />'.$row['store'].' - '.$row['store_name'].' - '.$row['branch_name'].'</label>';
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        FB::error($e);
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the contents of `$row['store']` and `$assigns`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss a space here `.'"'.$checked.'` and it should be `.'" '.$checked.'`

Comment: other things is fine (http://ideone.com/N6WFM3), check `$assigns` array and query

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head against that `in_array` conditional (writing it at least three different ways) and various table-joined `mysqli_query`s for two days before I gave up on either approach working. No matter what I did I could not get the code to check checkboxes automatically according to values in the array.

In the end I devised my own solution with jQuery and it works like a charm.

Check it out here if you are interested:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433841/1896348